# Using php DateTime object in mysql query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, php

I'm trying to create a query that pulls information about sellers from my database, but only if their store has launched in the last 3 days.  The easiest way I can think of to calculate the date for the query is using a `new DateTime()` object.  When I output my code to test it, it's in the proper string for MySQL to query it with, but whenever I try to bind the variable, I get an error.  I'm using Zend_Db to query, (PDO adapter)

action:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $dateMod = new DateTime();
    $dateMod->modify('-2 days');
    $dateMod->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    // get sellers initialized in last 3 days
    $sellerTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_Sellers();
    $select = $sellerTable->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
     $select->from(array('s' => 'seller'),array('sellerID', 'businessName'));
   // select firstName, lastName, picture from user table, and businessName and sellerID from seller table.  
   $select->join(array('u' => 'user'), 's.userID = u.userID', array('firstName', 'lastName', 'picture'));
   $select->where('s.active = 1 AND s.contentApproval = 1 AND s.paymentApproval = 1 AND s.featured = 1');
   $select->where('s.launchDate > ?', $dateMod);
   $select->order('s.launchDate DESC');
   $newSellers = $sellerTable->fetchAll($select);
```

When I assign `$dateMod` to the view, it outputs the correct `Y-m-d H:i:s` format. But when I plug it into the query, I get the following error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY `b`.`launchDate` DESC' at line 2
```

If I hardcode a value into dateMod in the mysql timestamp format, the query works fine.  How can I access just the string value of the timestamp in the DateTime object?  `getTimestamp` returns a unix formatted timestamp, even after assigning a format.

Comment: why not uses mysql's own date functions?

Comment: why not use mysql ADDDATE http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqldate/sql-date-add.shtml

Comment: I typically avoid using the mysql functions for dates.  I've found clients often change their minds about date functions, and putting it directly in the SQL means a lot of edits when the change is made.  If I do it with PHP, I can change an add time function to a sub time function just by passing a different parameter, and assign that to a front end feature the site admin can assign, and I can use the calculation very easily in the view.  But yes, that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format()` function *returns* the formatted date, so you need to assign that to a variable for use in the query:

```
$dateFormatted = $dateMod->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$select->where('s.launchDate > ?', $dateFormatted);
```