# php datetime insertion into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert the datetime into a column in a mysql table.

```
 <?php

//Some code

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//Other variables defined also

$date_time = new DateTime();


$queryreg = mysql_query ("

    INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$username','$password','$email','$website','$image','$date_time')

    ");



?>
```

However the browser states: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\design\register.php on line 181".  Any idea why it is doing this?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using php DateTime object in mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489386/using-php-datetime-object-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 5):

```
$date = $date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

INSERT INTO .... VALUES (..., '$date');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to typecase $date_time to string by surrounding it with '' in your SQL query. Either remove the surrounding quotes or convert to string by doing:

```
$date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` for the insertion, like this:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$website', '$image', '{$date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}')
```

I also suggest not using `mysql_*` functions but rather learn using `PDO` with prepared statements or at least `mysqli_*` functions.

Also sanitize Your input to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a string format for the date, like this:

date_format(variable, "string format")

date_format($date_time, "%m/%d/%y"), for example.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to have timestamp field in table with default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

But if you want to control manually this one then you need to convert DateTime object to a string like this:

```
<?php
//Some code
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//Other variables defined also
$date_time = new DateTime();

$queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES
      ('','$username','$password','$email','$website','$image',
      '{$date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}')");
?>
```